# Why git cherry-pick leaves uncommitted changes exits with non-zero

Tags: git-cherry-pick

Very often, my git appears like this:

```
 A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- HEAD
```

It happens that I need to create a new branch based on `B` and only the changes in `D`. Here are the commands I do:

```
git checkout B -q -f -b release
git cherry-pick D
```

The cherry pick commands exits with code 53 and leaves all the changes in `D` uncommitted in branch `release`.

More info: this is under Windows. The commands above are part of my release process which I run under PowerShell. When I do the same procedure in Git Bash, cherry pick works just fine. Is this (yet another) EOL issue? I tried adding `-Xignore-all-space` but error remains.

Context: as part of my release process, I pick a cut-off commit (e.g. `B`), modify version files to include build time, release author, etc. Just before I can commit my versioning changes, someone else introduces commit `C`. When I commit my versioning changes, it becomes `D`. My release process above is to ensure that binaries are compiled with `A <- B <- D`. How can I make that happen smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was my PATH var. I had it set like:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw32\bin"
```

I changed to:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw32\bin
```

And problem was solved.